# Get values from a select list using xpath

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to get the select list values using xpath because by id is giving me false in the exists function, but is not working

```
puts   $browser.select_list(:xpath,"//*[@id='numType']").exists?

number = $browser.select_list(:xpath,"//*[@id='numType']").options.map(&:text)

 number_list = Array.new
 number.each do |number_text|
      number_list << "#{number_text}"
 end
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="forwardRs">
<div class="forwardR">
<div id="forwardT" class="rc1">
  <select id="forward_types" name="Foward Types" tabindex="5" onchange="changeForwardTypes(this);">
    <option value="unconditional">unconditional</option>
    <option value="busy">busy</option>
    <option value="reply">reply</option>
    <option value="reachable">reachable</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="numtype" class="rc1" style="">
  <select id="numType" onchange="changeNumType(this);" name="numbers" tabindex="5">
    <option value="ex">Ex</option>
    <option value="in">In</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="rule" class="rc1" style="">
  <input id="tel" type="text" value="" size="20" name="tel" tabindex="2" onchange="changeNumberRule(this);">
</div>
<div id="removeForwardRule" class="rc3">
  <a onclick="removeForwardRule(this);">
   <img src="../../images/delete.png">
  </a>
```

How can i do this?

Tanks

Comment: Is this html taken directly from the page being tested?  Your first select list is never closed, there are multiple of the same ID numtype (which should be unique) and at least one of your divs are not closed, though that may just be because of the excerpt nature of the html.  I dont think any of these things are directly influencing your problem, but they're worth noting.

Comment: Wow that's like 15 tries at answering this for me now.  I don't see any problems in Webdriver on Firefox 3.6 using the html and watir that you gave (using in irb).  Are you getting some sort of error, or are you just not seeing the results you expect?  Also what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using firefox 7. Simply doesn't show anything.

Comment: if we presume ID's are case insensitive, then his are unique.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to closely examine the object returned by browser.select_list(:id, 'numType') to see what it is returning.  That or select it by its name (presuming that is unique)   Might be interesting to run in irb and see what `puts $browser.select_list(:id => 'numType']")` returns, and then try the same thing with .options on the end.   could we be looking at an issue in watir-webdriver with the .options method?

Comment: I tried `puts $browser.select_list(:id=>'numType').options` and it gives me `#<Watir::OptionCollection:0x7f31340dfd60>` and just with `puts $browser.select_list(:id=>'numType')` it show this `#<Watir::Select:0x7f551dfd6280>`.  When i try the .option.map(&:text) it returns nothing just blank lines.

Comment: Just out of interest have you tried this on the html that you're providing us with? (rather than in the full document)

Comment: no, i tried in the full document. Why?

Comment: I was wondering if perhaps something was populating those select lists dynamically and it's returning blank because the options _are_ blank when it checks them.  If you ran the same watir code against the html you've provided to us and it suddenly works, then the problem may be timing.

Comment: If i use `$browser.select_list(:id=>'numType').option.map(&:value)` instead of `:text` it gives me the value of the option. That is strange.

Comment: I found my problem it was a silly mistake. Every thing works great. Sorry from making you lose time in this thing and tank you very much for all the help you gave on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard what I originally wrote here, as I have been completely unsuccessful in getting the `.options` method to return any of the options in a select list, whereas the `.selected_options` method returns the selected options just fine.

I've been able to successfully get the options from your select list by doing the following:

```
select_list_options = $ff.elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='numType']/option")
```

which gives you an array of the options in the select list.

To get the text out of those elements I did

```
select_list_options_text = Array.new
select_list_options.each do |option|
  select_list_options_text << option.text
end
```

Not a very pretty answer but hey.

I have literally no idea why `.options` does not work for me, but you may be suffering the same problem.

Comment: oh okay that bizarre .map(&:text) is a more concise way of doing what I just wrote.  Excellent.  I'm going around in circles today.  And the .options doesn't work as I expected it to (returning an array of the values) but isn't completely broken as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I have created html file with the html from the question, and my Firefox 8 for some reason thinks that `option` tags are not inside `select` tag. See attached screen shot.[image]

Comment: I changed the html code, maybe i forgot something